# Bring a vast experience or Bring vast experience?

Tags: grammaticality

**I have the following sentence:**

*"We supply products and bring vast experience to help you achieve positive outcomes."*

**Should the sentence be read like so?**

*"We supply products and bring a vast experience to help you achieve positive outcomes."*

**or should it be like this:**

*"We supply products and bring vast experiences to help you achieve positive outcomes."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bring vast experience" is the correct usage.

Alternatively you could phrase it
"and our vast experience will help you achieve positive outcomes"

Comment: Please give supporting references (if only Google Ngrams) for your claim. Without such, answers come across as being possibly no more than personal opinion; many such answers have in fact been inaccurate. // Note that 'She has a working knowledge of Swahili' swings the other way.